# how to change showDatePicker input format flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter

I'm using showDatePicker function to pick a date from the dialog Calendar. It shows an edit icon at the top right (see img 1) to change to input mode  where the user can enter the date as a text (see img 2)
The problem is with the input format, I want that text editor input follow this format yyyy-mm-dd. The problem is that in the begning it show me the date like yyyy-mm-dd, but when the I try to remove the first number it changes automaticly to this format mm/dd/yyyy.

How to set the input format to  yyyy-mm-dd. If showDatePicker dont support that with the swedish language, so how to hide the edit icon for ever from the top right. Help me thanks

[image: img 1]
img 1

[image: img 2]
img 2

Here is my code

```
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  String date = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(DateTime.now()); 
...
FlatButton(
         onPressed: ()async {

           final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
               locale: const Locale('sv'), // Swedish calander
               context: context,
               initialDate: selectedDate,
               firstDate: DateTime(1970, 8),
               lastDate: DateTime(2101));

           if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
             setState(() {
               selectedDate = picked;
               String Onlydate = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(picked); 

               date = '$Onlydate';


             });
           }
         },
         child: Row(
           children: <Widget>[
             Text(' * $date'),
           ],
         ),
       );`
```

Comment: you can set desire date formate in datePicker with property locale('sv','SE') but before for that checkout my answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Flutter team solved this problem in the latest versions.

You can use the constructor parameter

`initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly`

to hide the text input. I don't know how to change the date format though.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, how to change the format of input date mode (as in the second image)

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Default `showDatePicker` using properties  `localizationsDelegates` & `supportedLocales` of  `MaterialApp` widget. so to change the input date formate you `must` to add `localizations` properties in your app `MaterialApp` widget otherwise you will get error when you pass `local` in `showDatePicker` picker.

> **(my flutter version `3.3.9`)**

**Here are steps which work from me.**

> **1. Add this in your `pubspec.yaml` file.**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations: # Add this line
    sdk: flutter         # Add this line
```

Also bellow packages too.
[localization](https://pub.dev/packages/localization)
& [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

> **2.update `MaterialApp` Widget code**

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
MaterialApp(
  title: 'APP NAME',
  localizationsDelegates: const [ 
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: const [
    Locale('en', 'GB'), // English, UK
    Locale('ar', 'AE'), // Arabic, UAE
    Locale('en', 'IN'), // English, India
  ],
  home:MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);
```

Now in `showDatePicker` widget add local parameters `(language, country)`.
so now user can add Date in `dd/MM/yyyy` formate without error message.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

// Declration.
final sDateFormate = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
String date = DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(DateTime.now());

ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
        locale: const Locale('en', 'GB'),
        context: context,
        fieldHintText: sDateFormate,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1970, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      );
    
      if (picked != selectedDate) {
        setState(() {
          selectedDate = picked!;
    
          date = DateFormat(sDateFormate).format(picked);
          
        });
      }
    },
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(' * $date'),
      ],
    ),
)
```

Here attaching useful url which contains country list with `langue code`, `country code` & `date formate` - [Link](https://gist.github.com/mlconnor/1887156)

[official link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) for localisation more in detail.

IF You want to **hide** Edit button in calendar add property in `showDatePicker`.

```
final DateTime? selectDate = await showDatePicker(
 initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly, // Hide edit button
....     //other properties
);
```

Comment: I'm from India and this one worked for me, by adding **locale: const Locale('en', 'IN')**, on the showDatePicker(). Now I can use the date format dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to remove the edit icon as of now. You can try some packages on building your own custom date picker from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker). This package supports swedish language too.