# Change date format in edit mode instead of picking a date in flutter showDatePicker()

Tags: flutter, datepicker, dateformatter

i am using showDatePicker() to pick a date in my flutter app. I changed the dateformat to my requirement i.e dd/MM/yyyy. everyting works fine but if i click the edit pen icon from the date picker and enter dd/MM/yyyy (15/10/2020)format then its shows invalid format.

please help me anyone on this. Here is my code.

```
TextFormField(
  controller: startDateAnnuityCtl,
  validator: (String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Enter Start date of annuity *';
    } else {
          _formObject.amrfNoAnnuityStartString = value;
    }
    return null;
  },
  onSaved: (String value) {
    _formObject.amrfNoAnnuityStartString = value;
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      isDense: true, // Added this
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Color(0xff5a9fd6).withOpacity(0.15),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Color(0xff5a9fd6).withOpacity(1.0),
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1.0),
      )),
  onTap: () async {
    formKey1.currentState.save();
    DateTime date = DateTime(1900);
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    date = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,

        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(1900),
        lastDate: DateTime(2100));
    if (date != null) {
      setState(() {
        var dtnew =
        new DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(date);
        _formObject.amrfNoAnnuityStartString = dtnew;
        startDateAnnuityCtl.text = _formObject.amrfNoAnnuityStartString;
      });
    }
  },
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

while entering date in the date picker, it takes the input in the format MM/dd/yyyy. Hence you are getting an error saying invalid format. Currently I found no solution to changing the textfield format in the date picker.

Comment: you found any solution ?

Comment: unfortunately no. @VishalZaveri

Comment: you can try this, checkout my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62073968/how-to-change-showdatepicker-input-format-flutter/75046427#75046427

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding the following lines in datepicker.

```
locale:  const Locale('en','IN'),
fieldHintText: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
```

```
showDatePicker(
                 locale:  const Locale('en','IN'),
                 context: context,
                 initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                 firstDate:DateTime.now(),
                 lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                 fieldHintText: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                 builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child){
                 .................... 
                 }
              );
```

Comment: its working in older version now in latest version (stable flutter - 3.3.6) not working.

Comment: For some reason this works with `Locale('en','IN')` and not `Locale('en','NZ')`. Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the best method but I created my own DefaultMaterialLocalizations and changed the behaviour of parseCompactDate method.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?

Comment: Please how did you do it? Can you share your code

Answer (score 0):

The date format will be set to US as default. This means that if the fieldHintText is null then the default date format is **en_US**, the same thing for the locale.

```
    locale:  const Locale('en','GB'), 
won't work unless US format even though you set `fieldHintText: 'dd/mm/yyyy'`
```

You will be able to see the hint text in the format you want however the date format will still be US.
Unfortunately, it seems that non_US formats are not yet implemented in the package. I found an alternate solution in another thread and used it in my code and it worked.

in your YAML add

```
flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

in your main file import and add

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

    localizationsDelegates: const [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: const [
            Locale('en', 'GB'),
          ],
```

and then all you need in your showDatePicker is fieldHintText: 'dd/mm/yyyy',

I hope this helps you.